# Matlab fourier descriptors what's wrong?

Tags: matlab, fft, fourier-descriptors

I am using Gonzalez `frdescp` function to get Fourier descriptors of a boundary. I use this code, and I get two totally different sets of numbers describing two identical but different in scale shapes.

So what is wrong?

```
im = imread('c:\classes\a1.png');
im = im2bw(im);
b = bwboundaries(im);
f = frdescp(b{1}); // fourier descriptors for the boundary of the first object ( my   pic only contains one object anyway )
// Normalization
f = f(2:20); // getting the first 20 & deleting the dc component
f = abs(f) ;
f = f/f(1);
```

Why do I get different descriptors for identical - but different in scale - two circles?

Comment: where did you get frdescp from? it may be the source of the problem

Comment: I got it from Gonzaelz's Digital image processing using MATLAB book , actually i think bwboundaries is the problem !

Comment: I edited [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23741097/738017), I hope it can be useful to you and other users.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `frdescp` code (I used [this code](https://beagle.whoi.edu/redmine/projects/ifcb-web/repository/revisions/2/show/trunk/dipum_toolbox_registered/dipum_1.1.3), that should be the same as referred by you) is written also in order to center the Fourier descriptors.

If you want to describe your shape in a correct way, it is mandatory to mantain some descriptors that are symmetric with respect to the one representing the DC component.

The following image summarize the concept:

[image: Cut-off of less significant descriptors]

In order to solve your problem (and others like yours), I wrote the following two functions:

```
function descriptors = fourierdescriptor( boundary )
    %I assume that the boundary is a N x 2 matrix
    %Also, N must be an even number

    np = size(boundary, 1);

    s = boundary(:, 1) + i*boundary(:, 2);

    descriptors = fft(s);

    descriptors = [descriptors((1+(np/2)):end); descriptors(1:np/2)];
end

function significativedescriptors = getsignificativedescriptors( alldescriptors, num )
    %num is the number of significative descriptors (in your example, is was 20)
    %In the following, I assume that num and size(alldescriptors,1) are even numbers

    dim = size(alldescriptors, 1);

    if num >= dim
        significativedescriptors = alldescriptors;
    else
        a = (dim/2 - num/2) + 1;
        b = dim/2 + num/2;

        significativedescriptors = alldescriptors(a : b);
    end
end
```

Know, you can use the above functions as follows:

```
im = imread('test.jpg');
im = im2bw(im);
b = bwboundaries(im);
b = b{1};

%force the number of boundary points to be even
if mod(size(b,1), 2) ~= 0
    b = [b; b(end, :)];
end

%define the number of significative descriptors I want to extract (it must be even)
numdescr = 20;

%Now, you can extract all fourier descriptors...
f = fourierdescriptor(b);
%...and get only the most significative:
f_sign = getsignificativedescriptors(f, numdescr);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the same problem with you.

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319251/fourier-transform-and-fourier-descriptors-to-extract-shapes-features-on-java), if you want invariant to scaling, make the comparison ratio-like, for example by dividing every Fourier coefficient by the DC-coefficient. f*[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319251/fourier-transform-and-fourier-descriptors-to-extract-shapes-features-on-java) = f[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319251/fourier-transform-and-fourier-descriptors-to-extract-shapes-features-on-java)/f[0], f*[2]/f[0], and so on. Thus, you need to use the DC-coefficient where the f(1) in your code is not the actual DC-coefficient after your step "f = f(2:20); % getting the first 20 & deleting the dc component". I think the problem can be solved by keeping the value of the DC-coefficient first, the code after adjusted should be like follows:

```
% Normalization
DC = f(1);
f = f(2:20); % getting the first 20 & deleting the dc component
f = abs(f) ; % use magnitudes to be invariant to translation & rotation
f = f/DC; % divide the Fourier coefficients by the DC-coefficient to be invariant to scale
```